# Grails show my URL in controller

Tags: url, grails

I am pulling the components of my URL. I used `request.getRequestURL()`, but my URL looks wrong: it's missing an ID, for example.

I'm getting this::

```
..//apka/grails/AAA/edit.dispatch"
```

But I need this:

```
..//apka/grails/AAA/edit/34"
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Please add some context: what URL are you trying to fetch, what information do you need in this URL, show us your code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the information you require from `request.forwardURI`, which is a Grails specific addition to the usual HttpServletRequest.  The result you're getting from `request.requestURL` is the *result* of the URL mapping mechanism, and is a kind of "canonical form" which is always `/grails/controller/action.dispatch`.  The `forwardURI` is what went *in* to the URL mapping mechanism, i.e. the URI that the user originally requested.